# Ubuntu meteor error

Tags: meteor

Not sure why but when I tried to run any meteor app (examples, new apps, current apps in develop) in my desktop I get this:

```
meteor
[[[[[ ~/tmp/lol ]]]]]

Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
Running on: http://localhost:3000/

/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/fiber-helpers.js:23
    }).run();
       ^
Error: watch ENOSPC
    at errnoException (fs.js:806:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:837:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:861:11)
    at _.extend._scan (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:424:24)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/lib/meteor/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at new DependencyWatcher (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:360:5)
    at exports.run.start_watching (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:593:17)
    at /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:651:5
    at exports.inFiber (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/fiber-helpers.js:22:12)
```

My office desktop has the same versions ( ubuntu,node,meteor) and works like a charm, already tried uninstalling meteor and node and the problem persist.

any idea?

Comment: What operating system is your desktop? Also how how free disk space do you have on this machine, finally are you running as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... found the problem, Dropbox is watching too many files, if I stop the dropbox meteor works as usual, to keep both working I have to edit /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches and set the number there to 100000 , after that both are ok

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command. That might help

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```